# Generalization of Fubini

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space, $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{A}) \rightarrow (E_{1},\mathcal{E}_{1}), Y:(\Omega,\mathcal{A}) \rightarrow (E_{2},\mathcal{E}_{2})$ be random variables s.t. the regular conditional distributions exist. Moreover let $f:E_{1}\times E_{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable w.r.t. $P^{(X,Y)}$.

Is there a nice way to express

$$
    \int_{\Omega}f(X,Y) \,dP=\int_{E_{1} \times E_{2}}f \,dP^{(X,Y)}
$$

similar to the case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent where one can use Fubini?

Can one write

$$
    \int_{\Omega}f(X,Y) \,dP=\int_{E_{2}}\int_{E_{1}}f(x,y) P^{X\mid Y=y}(dx)P^{Y}(dy)\, ?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The very definition of regular conditional distribution (of $X$ given $Y$, say) implies that
$$
P^{(X,Y)}(F)=\int_{E_2}P^{X|Y=y}(F^y) P^Y(dy),
$$
for each $F\in\mathcal E_1\otimes\mathcal E_2$, where $F^y$ is the section $\{x\in E_1: (x,y)\in F\}$. This then imples, by the usual simple function approximation, that
$$
\int_\Omega f(X,Y) dP=\int_{E_1\times E_2} f dP^{(X,Y)} =\int_{E_2}\left[\int_{E_1} f(x,y) P^{X|Y=y}(dx) \right]P^Y(dy)
$$
for non-negative $\mathcal E_1\otimes\mathcal E_2$-measurable $f$. For signed $f$, if $f(X,Y)\in L^1(P)$, then $f\in L^1(P^{(X,Y)})$ and for $P^Y$-a.e. $y$, the function $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is in $L^1(P^{X|Y=y})$ and the identity displayed above holds true. (Write $f$ as $f^+-f^-$, so that $\int f^+ dP+\int f^- dP<\infty$ because $f^++f_-=|f|$.)